# Analytics v4 reports are not showing

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics v4 in my app.I published my app now I can see users in real time analytics but other reports are empty.What can be cause this ? I started using analytics 2 days ago still there is no report.But as I said I can see users in real time analyics.

This is my tracker:

```
package com.impact.ribony;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

    public class Trackers extends Application
    {
        public enum TrackerName
        {
            APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this
                            // app.
            GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the
                            // apps from a company.
                            // eg: roll-up tracking.
            ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all
                                // ecommerce
                                // transactions from a
                                // company.
        }

        HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

        public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId)
        {
            if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId))
            {
                GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
                if( trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER )
                {
                    mTrackers.put(trackerId, analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker));
                }
            }
            return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
        }
    }
```

This is global_tracker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">


    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="com.impact.ribony.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>
    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-42075172-2</string>
</resources>
```

And I am using following lines in `onCreate()` method:

```
Tracker t = ((Trackers) getApplication()).getTracker(Trackers.TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName("Main");
t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

And this one in `onResume()` method:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about why there is no crash reports, than it is a known bug, maybe it is someway linked with your problem, more [here](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=443) In general exceptions are not dispatched even with this line in V4-

`<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>`

Edit. Maybe change to ScreenViewBuilder, because AppViewBuilder is deprecated.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder.html

Comment: No,this is not my question.I mean all reports are empty.Only I can see in real time analytics.